# How to merge two tables by datetime

Tags: excel, datetime, merge, vlookup

I have a table in excel that is datetime minute by minute.
I also have another table that is datetime but its 5 in 5 minutes.
I want to put the data from the second table on the first table
I have tried the vlookup, index and match, but nothing seems to work. 
I dont want to go and put one by one of the 5 min data. There is anyway to do it automatically?
 Thanks

first table

[image]
[first data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st3Ct.png)

second table

[image]
[second data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewYa6.png)

Comment: Have you tried to append the second table and then sort on the date column?

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to do it. I tried to find a way to sort the  first table in 5 min interval but i didnt find a way to do it... I know that it maybe is a simple question, but is killing me here.

Comment: Do you want the first table to show the values for the nearest time from the second table? More sophisticated would be an interpolation between the table 2 values but that might be more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Vlook up for this , I Created an example for this[image: This is sheet One]

Do ignore the column title for now only focus on Column and Row index No for understand the formula

[image: Sheet2]

Now in sheet1 we need to add column and put formula there
[image: Sheet3]

Formula for

E2 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"NO Value")`

E3 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"NO Value")`

E4 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"NO Value")`

and so on...

Formula for

C2 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE),"NO Value")`

C3 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE),"NO Value")`

C4 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE),"NO Value")`
and so on...

Here A1,A2,A3 is the Date ColumnRowIndex , Then we use next Sheet(Sheet2) where in which range we need to look , then the column value we need to copy from next Sheet(Sheet2) ,FALSE use for exact match
We wrapped whole Vlookup formula in IF error so in case no matching value found default text of "NO value" will be shown there

you just need to drag the pointer for autofill the formula

Comment: It worked perfectly!! you are the man!! thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome :) , happy to help